# jquery autocomplete rendering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to implement the jQuery autocomplete plugin by receiving the data through a servlet.
The script works and it does pull the results from the servlet but I can't get it to render properly in the drop down menu. Say I write "hel" in the search bar, the autocomplete drop down list is:

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

From what I understand, the autocomplete plugin is supposed to receive an array and I think that may be the issue. 
This is my javascript code:

```
<script>
function getFilteredNames(request, response){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../servlet/Autocomplete", 
        data: request,
        success: function(data) {
            response(data);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#buscar").autocomplete({ source : getFilteredNames, minLength: 3}); 
});
</script>
```

And this is part of the servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {
            String query = request.getParameter("term");
            List<Socio> rs = new ArrayList<Socio>();    
            rs = SocioDAO.getSociosByQuery(query);      

                if (rs.isEmpty()) {
                    out.println("No hay coincidencias");
                }
                else {

                    Iterator <Socio> iterator = rs.iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        String nombre = (String) iterator.next().getNombre();
                        out.println(nombre);
                    }

            }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but, looking at the JavaScript, I'm not seeing how the request is getting to the servlet at all

Comment: I'm sending the data with the data: request and I pick it on the servlet by using request.getParameter("term") and what I type on the search box comes up.

Comment: I see that but how is request getting populated? I see in the autocomplete function you specify what the source function is...but how to you pass the parameters to it? Namely, request and response?

Comment: In the servlet? I use request.getParameter("term") and if I print it out to console I can see what I am typing in the webpage. Then I perform a database search in the servlet and return the results. The issue is that instead of printing out the whole result in a line it gives each character a line. I'm thinking it might be because I have to send an array to the response (in the out.println) but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autocomplete UI plugin accepts array,object formatted in JSON data.

1. So u have to put datatype:json in ur $.ajax Call
2. As u r using servlet u have to format it in json format before
   sending to client side through ajax call.

for converting ur  data to json format u can use utility call provided by http://www.json.org/

Comment: Ok I'll give it a try and let you know! Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @user1207556 The pleasure is completely mine. Happy coding :)